# Why doesn't React.js fire onKey* event handlers for the Escape key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apparently, React doesn't fire onKey* event handlers (such as `onKeyDown` and `onKeyPress`) if the key being pressed is `Escape` and the focus is on an input element. In other words, nothing will be printed on the console when I press the Escape key when the focus is on the input element in this component:

```
const Input = () => {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={...}
      onChange={...}
      onKeyDownCapture={(e) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
          console.log("onKeyDownCapture: ", e);
        }
      }}
      onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
          console.log("onKeyDownCapture: ", e);
        }
      }}
      onKeyPress={(e) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
          console.log("onKeyDownCapture: ", e);
        }
      }}
      onKeyUp={(e) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
          console.log("onKeyDownCapture: ", e);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

[Here is a codesandbox to try it out yourself](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-lcmbe9?file=/src/App.tsx).

Why is that?

Comment: Events are fired by the *browser*, not by React.

Comment: FYI: The [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) event is deprecated.

Comment: Also if you want to debug this, you need to `console.log()` the event and the key property **outside** your `if` statements.

Comment: @Pointy So how can I handle the Escape key?

Comment: Your codesandbox code is working perfectly well for me (Safari).

Comment: @Pointy I'm using chrome. Maybe that's a chrome issue

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a chromium issue. Firefox doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, it also works in Chrome on MacOS.

Comment: I'm using Chromium 101.0.4951.64 on Arch Linux. I guess I have to update my browser. This is probably an issue with my setup. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the [`KeyboardEvent` types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#events) supported by React's [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events) are:

> ```
> onKeyDown onKeyPress onKeyUp
> ```

I don't identify the issue that you describe when visiting your CodeSandbox link, but here's an example which demonstrates a single listener which logs the event `type` and `key` bound to each of those events, in order for you to experiment/explore and reproduce success in your code:

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.18.11/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const logKeyboardEventMeta = (ev) => console.log(ev.type, JSON.stringify(ev.key));

function Input () {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      onKeyDown={logKeyboardEventMeta}
      onKeyPress={logKeyboardEventMeta}
      onKeyUp={logKeyboardEventMeta}
    />
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

reactRoot.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Input />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

</script>
```

Comment: Apparently, this is a chrome (actually chromium) issue. Your example works perfectly in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: @Arman Works for me in Chrome `104.0.5112.79` on macOS

Comment: I'm using Chromium 101.0.4951.64 on Arch Linux. I guess I have to update my browser. This is probably an issue with my setup. Thank you so much for the help.